# compute number of minibatches for numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, perceptron

I am trying to implement a multi-layer perceptron deep network. I am using [this](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/mlp.html#mlp) tutorial. I am using my own dataset. I want to compute the number of minibatches for training, validation and testing sets. However, I am getting this error:

```
x: test_set_x[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size],
IndexError: failed to coerce slice entry of type TensorVariable to integer
```

I am using numpy arrays in my code. And here it is my code:

```
batch_size=20



index = T.lscalar()  # index to a [mini]batch


test_model = theano.function(
    inputs=[index],
    outputs=classifier.errors(y),
    givens={
        x: test_set_x[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size],
        y: test_set_y[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size]
    }
)
```

Any thoughts??

Comment: Where is the line where the error is occuring, can't find it in your code.

Comment: @Benjamin I solved the problem with defining the test_set_x variable as a shared variable. Thanks

Comment: The massive edits make things a bit hard to follow, but glad you solved your issue.